# ko.pager hookup with real data

Tags: knockout.js, pagination

to be very specific Guys,

I need help to know how to hook up ko.pager (from https://github.com/remcoros/ko.pager) to our real data.

I make JQuery Ajax call as below

```
   $.ajax({
    url: config.EnvironmentDomain + config.ProductController + '/?PageSize=' + pageSize  
    + '&ActiveOnly=' + activeOnly +'&Index=' + startIndex,                   
    type: "GET",
        success: function (data)
        {
           ko.applyBindings(new RealDataVeiwModel(data), document.getElementById('EachProductList'));
           ko.applyBindings(new PagerViewModel(data.length), document.getElementById('pg'));
        },
        error: function () { }
    });
```

Can you please explain me the Plumbing here so that,

if AJAX Call returns 150 records from Database and on my page 15 records will be displayed per page and ko.pager navigation also should work ?

I am new to Knockout.js and your help will encourage me to learn it more. I will appreciate your help.

Regards.

Comment: Could you please update your question so that it's more specific, perhaps include some more ViewModel and View code? Tell us what you've tried, and why your current solution didn't work.

Comment: Jeroen, I get JSON data from my AJAX Call. I am not being able to HOOK up this JSON Data (let's say 150 records) to ko.pager so it can display 15 records per page and shows Pagination for 10 Pages (150 total records devided by 15 record per page). When I pass data.length to PageViewModel, it shows Pagination correctly, but NAVIGATION of clicking on Page Numbers, Last, Previous, Next, First Do not work. https://github.com/remcoros/ko.pager has working example but does not seem to be fitting to what I am doing. Let me know.

Comment: Or very simply, how can I hook up ko.pager from Githug to my JSON Data?

Comment: Hey hey, I can understand the generics of your question, just not the specifics. Can you update the question and add some more code, show us what you've tried so far? (Note that you can edit your question to add more details.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, playing with this, I got the solution working. Here it is....

So, I make AJAX Call as usual to get data from Server

```
$.ajax({
url: config.EnvironmentDomain + config.ProductController + '/?PageSize=' + ps + '&ActiveOnly=' + 
ao + '&Index=' + si,
type: "GET",
async: false,
success: function (data) {                        

ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel(data.length), document.getElementById('pg'));
dataFromServer = data;
Rendering();
},
error: function () { }
});
```

where dataFromServer is simple JS Global Variable to just temporarily hold data(in JSON) from server.

And my Rendering functions does DHTML

```
function Rendering(){
var fromPage = parseInt($(".pagexofx").children(".FI").text());
var toPage = parseInt($(".pagexofx").children(".LI").text());    
var totalCount = dataFromServer.length;
var si = fromPage - 1;
var ei = toPage;

for (var x = si; x < ei; x++) {
div.append('<ul id="eachProd" style="list-style: none" class="remove">' +
'<li>' +
'<div style="border:2px solid black;" class="span4">' +
'<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong><span>' + dataFromServer[x].Name + '</span></strong></p>' +
'<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>SKU:</strong><span>&nbsp;<strong>' + dataFromServer[x].SKU     
+ '</strong></span></p>' +
'<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Last Updated:</strong><span>&nbsp;' + getFormattedDate(dataFromServer
[x].LastUpdateTS) + '</span></p>' +
'&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
href="">Qty./Price</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
'<a href="">Copy</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;/&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="">Delete</a>' +
'</div>' +
'</li>' +
'</ul>'
)
}   
}
```

my PageView Model is below here....

```
var PageViewModel = function (len) {    
var self = this;
self.SetTotalResults = ko.observable(30);
// holds the total item count
self.TotalResults = ko.observable(len);
// actual pager, used to bind to the pager's template    
self.Pager = ko.pager(self.TotalResults);
// Subscribe to current page changes.
self.Pager().CurrentPage.subscribe(function () {       
    self.search();
});
self.search = function () {  
    self.TotalResults(dataFromServer.length);
}
```

} // /ViewModel